# urllib.parse I am trying to parse a url however it is parsing part of it and not all

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, urllib, python-2.x

here I have a url:

`https://www.httpbin.org/get?course=networking&assignment=1`

and I want to parse it so that I can do something like this:

```
remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(addr)
message = "GET /get?course=networking&assignment=1 HTTP/1.1\nHost: " +remote_ip +"\n\n"
```

However It is only giving me part of the url and missing the rest.
I am storing the url in a variable called address and parsing it as follows:

```
parsed = urlparse(address)
```

and I only get this:
`ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.httpbin.org', path='/get', params='', query='course=networking', fragment='')`

Answer (score 1):

```
import socket
from urllib.parse import urlparse
url = 'https://www.httpbin.org/get?course=networking&assignment=1'
res = urlparse(url)
remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname(res.netloc)
message = "GET {path}?{query} HTTP/1.1\nHost: {ip}\n\n".format(path=res.path, query=res.query, ip=remote_ip)
```

out:

```
'GET /get?course=networking&assignment=1 HTTP/1.1\nHost: 54.175.219.8\n\n'
```

use `.` to get info in the `ParseResult`

ParseResult:

```
ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='www.httpbin.org', path='/get', params='', query='course=networking&assignment=1', fragment='')
```

Comment: I know but what you dont see is that &assignment=1 is missing, I am not able to get it...

Comment: well its just that I need the whole path in order to make my get request, otherwise it will not work, like this:

`message = "GET /get?course=networking&assignment=1 HTTP/1.1\nHost: " +remote_ip +"\n\n"`

Comment: How? I am doing the exact same thing... and I am not able to get??

Comment: ooo, I just saw what is wrong, so when I pass this url through my cmd as a argument it only takes it until course=networking

Comment: do you know why that happens? is '&' reserved for something special in python?

Comment: @puzzle put url in quote or escape it

Comment: yeah that was the problem...smh

Comment: @puzzle http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work